# How to remove a product's attribute value

Tags: product, attributes, model, ce-1.8.0.0

I am updating produts programmatically and it sometimes happens that an attribute for a product is not used anymore. In that case, the attribute value should of course be removed. However, I can not find a way to do that. The update works just fine, but values aren't getting removed from the model.

I have looked around a bit and it seemed that the following would be the solution:

```
$product->unsetData($attributeCode);
```

But this does not remove the value. The attribute code is correct and everything else works perfectly fine. I also checked and it does use the right store.

I have gotten suggestions on doing this directly through the database, but I'd rather do it on the model for safety.

Comment: Try `$product->setData($attributeCode, null);`

Comment: $_Product->setAttributeCode(null); you can also use this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest making the attribute's value empty:

```
$product->setData($attributeCode, '');
```

or:

```
$product->setAttributeCode('');
```

or, as you have saved the product you need to save the product object:

```
$product->unsetData($attributeCode);
$product->save();
```

This will take effect after the object is saved.

Comment: That makes so much sense, setting the value to nothing. I feel stupid now.. Thanks!

Comment: This works fine, I have added the full code in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full code. This works fine for removing/empty attribute value.

`foreach ($collection as $item) {
 $mypro = "PRODUCT ENTITY ID"; 
$productRepository=$objectManager>get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product = $productRepository->getById($mypro);
$product->setData("PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_CODE_GOES_HERE", '');
$product->save();
}`

Comment: Question is about magento  1.X.Not Magento 2.X